# Categories positions in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, histogram, distribution, categories

I'm trying to implement distribution histogram in highcharts. That is simple histogram but I want to put percents values as categories between the columns and '0%' in the middle of the middle column. I'm trying to move categories with tick positions and using multiple axis but that doesn't help. 
That what I got now, hope that helps to understand what I'm trying to do.

```
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwbyyang/)
```

I need to move '-25%', '-10%', '-5%', '5%', '10%', '25%' to ticks grid lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense with the numbers given (the distance between 0 and 5% is 1.5 times the distance between 5 and 10%), but using three x axes and the x property of the labels, this is possible.

`example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/cwbyyang/2/

  `labels: { 
    x:-40 
  }`

Comment: I need to use that numbers but columns with different width looks weird to my mind. Your solution works great when the plot have fixed size. Thats fine for me. Thank you.